# Using a promise in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I think I need (but I'm not sure) to use a promise in my Angularjs app. This following code is within my controller and it calls a `.service` (not a `.factory` if that's relevant?) called `processString`.

```
//complete this first
var item = MagicBoxService.processString(str); 

//and then do this      
$scope.task.items.push({ content_type: item.content_type, provider: item.provider, front: item.front, data: item.data });
$scope.save = true;
```

The service needs to communicate with a 3rd party API (as well as my own) to get the data. This happens very quickly but the `item` variable is empty when the next part of the code is executed.

I've tried a `$timeout` on the API call but this doesn't seem to work so I thought maybe a promise is what I need to use so I've tried the following:

```
var item = MagicBoxService.processString(str).then(function() { 
    $scope.task.items.push({ content_type: item.content_type, provider: item.provider, front: item.front, data: item.data });
    $scope.save = true;
})
```

but this gives me **undefined is not a function**. Any advice/code would be much appreciated.

**EDIT**
Here is an edited version of my `.service`.

```
this.processString = function(str) {

  ...

  oEmbedService.query({url: str}, function(response) {
    item.content_type = "image";
    item.provider = "Flickr";
    item.data = response.content.url;
    item.front = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(item.data);
  })

   ...

  return item
};
```

Comment: your MagicBoxService service should return a promise  for this approach

Comment: ok, that might be beyond me. Let me post a trimmed version of my service into the question to see how it could be modified

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your `processString()` function looks like this:

```
function(str) {
    var promiseManager = $q.defer();

    ...

    oEmbedService.query({url: str}, function(response) {
        var item = {};
        item.content_type = "image";
        item.provider = "Flickr";
        item.data = response.content.url;
        item.front = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(item.data);

        promiseManager.resolve(item);
    })

    ...

    return promiseManager.promise;
};
```

Then you can call it like this:

```
MagicBoxService.processString(str).then(function(item) { 
    $scope.task.items.push({ content_type: item.content_type, provider: item.provider, front: item.front, data: item.data });
    $scope.save = true;
})
```

Comment: I've just added my `processString` to the question - could you edit your response?

Comment: Actually - I just missed the item in the controller - working fine.

Comment: However, (and this wasn't clear in the question) there are other operations in the processString that don't require a promise so how do I deal with this on the controller end? Thanks by the way!

Comment: I'm getting `undefined is not a function` when I call the service with a string that doesn't require a call to the API (and therefore not wrapped up in a promise).